# How to ban listview's scroll up/down animation in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

My listview just has a few items, and I don't want to scroll up and down.
So how to ban it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the never scroll physics

```
ListView(..., physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhsics())
```